# Can elements inserted by AJAX delay DOM loading? When is the DOM considered loaded?

Tags: ajax, dom, jquery

If we have a page which executes Javascript upon loading, and this Javascript inserts new  elements via AJAX, will this delay the time it takes for the DOM to be considered loaded?

Some of our UI only functions after the DOM is loaded (using jQuery's "ready" function), and we thought inserting page elements asynchronously via AJAX would load the DOM faster, increase perceived responsiveness, and allow users to interact with the page sooner. If this is right, we are doing something wrong.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do, you want to load the page and then load the content asynchronously. If you want to do this to improve perceived load speeds, run your ajax code from your `$(function(){});` call, not before. This fires when the DOM has loaded, which means all the rest of your page (except what you're trying to load asynchronously) has loaded.

The effect the user will perceive is that the whole page except the content loads (I assume you'll have some sort of spinning image or something where your content is going to be loaded), then you make the call, then you remove the loading icon and insert your content.

Comment: Thanks, Jason. So if the page executes Javascript on page load, and this Javascript inserts new elements via AJAX, the DOM is not considered loaded until these new elements are inserted? Our understanding was the AJAX-inserted elements, because they were asynchronously inserted, would not slow down other non-JS elements (e.g., DIV elements that come afterward) from getting rendered.

Comment: it depends on where in your pageload the javascript is. do you have it in the `<head>` or right before the `</body>` tag? `document.ready` fires once the DOM has been loaded. it doesn't care about any ajax calls you're making because it doesn't know what you're doing with the ajax call.

Comment: The Javascript is about midway between the <body> and </body> tag, but since it's asynchronous, it shouldn't materially slow down the loading of subsequent DOM elements, right?

Comment: the actual execution of javascript is what's called "blocking" meaning that while it is running, nothing else can run. this is up to the point where it actually sends off the AJAX request to the server. once it is waiting for a response, loading continues and the response is handled when it returns.

Comment: Exactly ... we assumed once the request is dispatched, the loading of subsequent DOM elements should resume. However, we're not seeing this. We're seeing that the whole DOM is not loaded until all those AJAX elements are inserted and all those asynchronous Javascript calls return with a result.

Comment: post your code. that's the only way we'll be able to see for sure.